# Regular Expression for AlphaNumeric, Hyphen and Underscore without any space

Tags: regex

I would like to have a regular expression that checks if the string contains Alphanumerics, Hyphen and Underscore. There should not be any spaces or other special characters other these three. My string will be under either of these 2 patterns.

- `XYZ0123_123456`
- `ABCdefGHI-727`

I have already tried this expression. But it didnt workout. `[[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*]`

Comment: This is marked as duplicate, but beware that the duplicate tag points to a javascript answer and OP is asking for the answer for Java.

Comment: It is all the same in all regex flavors.

Answer (score 26):

**Working**
Here is the quick solution.

```
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$";
sampleString.matches(regex);
```

- (^) anchor means start of the string
- ($) anchor means end of the string
- A-Z , a-z represent range of characters
- 0-9 represent range of digit
- ( _ ) represent underscore
- ( - ) represent hyphen

Comment: How is it different from @ThomasAyoub answer?

Comment: Gautam tried to implement [[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*]   expression I just post a detailed answer with the additoin of  code i think this can help beginner as well.

Comment: What if I want to accept spaces too?

Comment: works flawlessly @abubaker

Comment: @Gaurav Enjoy :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `^[\w-]*$` where `\w` means:

- any letter in the range `a-z`, `A-Z`,
- any digit from `0 to 9`,
- `underscore`

---

The error you made was to encapsulate you correct regex (`[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*` == `[\w-]*`) within a character class, loosing the quantifier (`*`) meaning

Comment: Should i include ^ and $ also in the regex?

Comment: @GautamR `^` and `$` are anchors. They means start (`^`) and end (`$`) of string. If you want your string to be **only** composed by alphanum, underscore and hyphen, yes, include it :)

Comment: it worked!!! Thanks :)

Comment: it works well for `ABCdefGHI-727` but it fails for `XYZ0123_123456`. Is there anything we are missing?

Comment: @GautamR it's *impossible* that the regex doesn't match `XYZ0123_123456`. The error is coming from the code around it, edit your question :)

Comment: I dont think so... This just a 4-5 line of code, which works for 1 pattern and fails for the other sounds fishy ;).

Comment: @GautamR it [does work.](https://ideone.com/9iJvn1)